# Setting a variable at run time

Tags: nsis

I am making an NSIS script which checks if a previous version of the application is installed. If so, it asks whether or not the configuration file should be imported from this previous version. So I have a global variable **config file** which I am trying to set at runtime depending on whether the user chooses "yes" or "no". The problem I am having is when compiling it complains with **File: "${XMLConfigDir}*.xml" -> no files found.** because XMLConfigDir has not been set yet. So is there anyway to set a variable at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to use the CopyFiles built in function rather than the SetOutPath followed by File.

Answer (score 12):

There is difference between declaring variables (**Var** command) and symbols (defined with **!define** command):

```
Var /GLOBAL myVar ; This is variable -> use it as $myVar

!define mySymbol; This is symbol -> use it as ${mySymbol}
```

Try this:

```
!define XMLConfigDir "C:\some_path_to_XML\subdir\"

Section "Main Section" 
        File "${XMLConfigDir}*.xml"
SectionEnd
```

Symbols can be also set using **/D** command line switch during installer runtime.

Comment: /D switch can be also used during compilation as: makensis.exe /DmySymbol="C:\some_path_to_XML\subdir\" script_to_compile.nsi

Comment: Cheers for the info but I don't understand how it answers my question of not being able to use the File command with a variable which is unknown at compile time but determined at runtime.